How common are common colds caused by latent viruses?
Contrary to common lore, many viruses can stick around ("are latent") in your body even after you recover from the disease they had caused. These include "herpes simplex virus, varicella zoster virus, Epstein–Barr virus, human cytomegalovirus, human herpesvirus 6, human herpesvirus 7, Kaposi‘s sarcoma-associated herpesvirus, JC virus, BK virus, parvovirus and adenovirus" [1], with the last one causing cold/flu-like symptoms. These viruses can then flare up ("reactivate") once more and cause problems, with a well-known example being herpes (recurring cold sores) or varicella zoster (chickenpox virus causing a shingles infection in adulthood).
It is often said that cold/flu comes about only from being exposed to airborne virus particles, but the fact that adenoviruses already in your body can reactivate presents an alternative mechanism. If this mechanism is behind a significant percent of cases, it would necessitate new policies advising the public on how to minimize the chance of reactivation.
What fraction of colds in a given person is caused by viruses they picked up from others vs. viruses in their own virome reactivating due to, e.g., colder temperature or stress?
Along those lines, how important is it to keep warm in a cold environment? If being colder increases the risk of reactivating a latent virus, shouldn't we care more about that? In particular, how does this apply to children, who get cold faster?

[Cross posted on Biology.SE.] Hi Victor.  Posting the same question on multiple sites is frowned upon on the entire SE network. Pick one site and stick with it. Please delete one of your posts. Also, research is required on both sites you posted to, not just any research, but research attempting to answer your question yourself, which in this case is the probability of upper respiratory illnesses being caused by latent viruses. Finally, one question per question. Keeping warm is a second question, and has been answered here already. Thanks.

From what I saw in a brief literature review reactivation of adenovirus only occurs in people who are immunocompromised. Do you have any sources indicating that it can reactivate and cause disease in healthy individuals?

Also, you need to address the issues @anongoodnurse pointed out.

I've retracted my flag as the version on biology has now been deleted. The question still needs prior research added though.
